# Android: working with the Twitter search api

Tags: android, twitter

I'm working on an Android app that works intensively with the Twitter search api, retrieving twitts that contain certain keywords, and then tokenizing other words in them. My question is the following: form an architectural point of view, is it better to do all the work inside the app or to retrieve the information from a webservice? (I was considering this last option at f
first, but I'm afraid that even caching the results wouldn't be enough to bypass the limit rates of the Twitter api).